# Illustrator: How to copy the properties of object A to object B WITHOUT the color?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, eyedropper

If there's easier way, let me know.

Comment: if you doubleclick on the eyedropper tool then it gives you options as to what to transfer. Maybe thats enough. Wont work with complicated styles though

Comment: What "properties" are you trying to copy???

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate A. Copy the color of B to the duplicate. Delete B. The duplicate is now your new object B. Everything except the color is taken from A.